# StorageFile still locked after writing

Tags: c#, uwp

I have the following code to write a CSV file:

```
public static async Task WriteCSVFile(StorageFile file, List<string>[] data)
{
    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
        var dataWriter = new DataWriter(outputStream)
        {
            UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8
        };

        for (int x = 0; x < data[0].Count; x++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)
            {
                dataWriter.WriteString(data[i][x]);
                dataWriter.WriteString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator);
            }
            dataWriter.WriteString(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
        await outputStream.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

This work well but when I try to open the writed file while the application still running, it's locked.

Something is still locking the file outside of the using part.
Have you some tip to fix this ?

Comment: Are you sure the task returned from `WriteCSVFile()` has completed?

Comment: As @MatthewWatson says, the code seems right; so the only thing I can think is that the task isn't finished.

Comment: This function is called by an other one running as a Task, it is awaited and finished without error. Do I have to force this Task to end in order to release the file?

Comment: DataWriter also requires disposal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many workarounds, I finally fix it by calling the garbage collector after awaiting the task. It seems that the StorageFile wasn't cleaning himself.

This is the new calling:

```
await SpreadsheetHelper.WriteCSVFile(fileExport, dataExport);
GC.Collect();
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I'll be glad to do it but I apparently must wait 48h since it's my own.

Comment: Sure. This could help others who are facing the same issue.